# How can I map an ontology components to a relational database?

Tags: python, mysql, relational-database, semantic-web, ontology

I already have an owl ontology which contains classes, instances and object properties. How can I map them to a relational data base such as MYSQL using a Python as a programming language(I prefer Python) ?
**For example**, an ontology can contains the classes: "Country and city" and  instances like: "United states and NYC". 
So I need manage to store them in relational data bases' tables. I would like to know if there is some Python libraries to so.

Comment: is there any reason why you're not using an RDF database to store and query your data?

Comment: I'm using OWL, is there any problem with that? I think owl can formulate an ontology too ? right ?

Comment: There's nothing special about OWL that an RDF database couldn't store, there's a defined mapping from OWL to RDF triples. Whether or not the rdf database supports reasoning is another matter. But a relational db won't, so I'm guessing that does not matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, I think you could use SQLite with python. SQLite is great because you have just to import the library with :

```
import sqlite3
```

And then, there is no need for a server. Things are stored in a file, gerenaly ending with : `.db`

Have a look at the doc, the example are helpful : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

**EDIT :**  To review or create your database and tables, I advise you tu use sqlitebrowser, which is light and easy to use : http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: Sorry, in my case I need to store the ontology elements in a relational database in order to run over them some SQL queries. For example, an ontology can contains the classes: "Country and city" and  instances like: "United states and NYC". So I will manage to store them in relational data bases' tables. I would like to know if there is some Python libraries to so. or alternatives...

Comment: How about creating tables "agents" with the columns "country", "city", etc... and in each raw you create an instance with "USA" and "NYC" to fill the column ?
Or maybe I missunderstood you and you want a library that actually does this for you, so you would'nt have to process the sql stuff yourself ?

Comment: I wanna parse the ontology and create the corresponding tables with their content. I'm not asking about the conceptual modeling of the database. I'm really talking about the manner of mapping an ontology to some tables. I wanna know HOW to do so.

Comment: Ok I understand better know ! May I ask how is currently stored your ontology ? Is it stuff on a paper or a text file or other thing ?

Comment: A file with ".owl" extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job. You're using RDF, that it's OWL axioms is immaterial, and you want to store and query it. Use an RDF database. They're optimized for storing and querying RDF. It's a waste of your time to homegrow storage & query in MySQL when other folks have already figured out how best to do this.

As an aside, there is a way to map RDF to a relational database. There's a formal specification for this, it's called R2RML.